Data type mismatch when selecting dates in MS Access
I would like to query records between two dates in MS access.  The date field is a string that I convert to a date format using the function below.  devicelocaltime is passed in as a string and the cvt2date returns a date.  The function works fine and when I check the vartype of the returned data, it returns a '7' indicating cvt2date is actually a date.  When I add search criteria in Design View as a date or daterange, I receive a datatype mismatch.  When I debug, the last line of the function is highlighted - cvt2date = CDate(new_date).  What am I doing wrong?
Thanks.

Public Function cvt2date(deviceLocalTime As String) As Date

Dim m, d, y, new_date As String


If deviceLocalTime = "" Then

new_date = "1/2/1900"

Else

y = Right(deviceLocalTime, 4)
m = Mid(deviceLocalTime, 5, 3)
d = Mid(deviceLocalTime, 9, 2)

new_date = m & "/" & d & "/" & y

End If

'cvt2date = Format(CDate(new_date), 2)
'cvt2date = new_date
cvt2date = CDate(new_date)
End Function



The query works fine until I add date search criteria.  Then I received the datatype mismatch error.

Use indentation in code to make it more readable.

Using the original function, the dates return as 5/2/2024 with vartype = 7.
The string passed into the function is Thu May  2 12:42:42 2024 with vartype = 8.  When I set the search criteria as Date(), the debugger crashes in the function at the cvt2date = CDate(new_date) line.  Using the function provided in the suggested answer, the query doesn't run and spits out the data type mismatch right away.

I have tested your function with the sample data you show in comment (should be within your question). No error, function works for me. Yes, if you use Date() as input, the function will error. Add an If Then test in your code to see if input is valid date before trying to parse: If IsDate(deviceLocalTime) Then

@BrianBrown When you debug that error you get at cvt2date = CDate(new_date), what does Debug.Print new_date show you?

Thanks for the tip.  I'm new to this so, I assumed to just put the Debug.Print new_date statement above the cvt2date = CDate(new_date) line.  When the query crashed and I entered the debugger, placing the cursor over the variable showed a very unusual result:    new_date = "/20/4,/4 PM"

OK.  Now, how did new_date wind up containing that string?  What does Debug.Print "'" & deviceLocalTime & "'" show you when you get that error?

@HansUp, example of input value in earlier comment. OP advised to edit question to show SQL and sample data.

@June7 Right.  I suspect Brian showed us a sample value which does not trigger the error.  We need to see the value which does trigger the error.  And I agree the question should include sample values, ideally indicating which of them trigger the error.

It returns deviceLocalTime = "4/17/2024, 1:40:34 PM"

But "4/17/2024, 1:40:34 PM" is a totally different format that the one , "Thu May 2 12:42:42 2024", your function was built to handle.

Whoa!  We're on to something.  I looked at deviceLocalTime in my table and the formats are all over the place.  on one row I see Mon Apr 29 15:56:18 2024, and the next row I see 4/30/2024, 9:53:35 AM, and in another row I see 2024-05-13 16:36:16.  It's obvious that the parsing out of the date needs to be different based on format.  Might anyone know of an elegant way to overcome the formatting issue in the raw data?

With those inconsistent formats, it will be challenging to parse them correctly to produce valid dates.  Don't know about your situation, but I would much prefer to store those values as actual Date/Time instead of text datatype.  Can you make that happen?

Yeah, there's legacy crap data in the database that needs to be addressed somehow.  I do have datetime2 data available, but that's stored at GMT time in another field.  I also have a time zone field I can use to add hours to get the device local time, but the function(s) would be complex to modify the dates if GMT time is on a different day than local time.

Converting from GMT to Local should be easier than dealing with that mishmash string data.

You can boil it down to:
Public Function cvt2date(ByVal deviceLocalTime As String) As Date

    Dim LocalTime   As Date

    ' Parse input like "Thu May 22 12:42:42 2024"
    deviceLocalTime = Mid(deviceLocalTime, 5, 4) & Mid(deviceLocalTime, 8, 3) & Right(deviceLocalTime, 5)
    
    If IsDate(deviceLocalTime) Then
        LocalTime = CDate(deviceLocalTime)
    Else
        LocalTime = DateSerial(1900, 1, 2)
    End If

    cvt2date = LocalTime
    
End Function

This also takes care of invalid values for argument deviceLocalTime which probably is the cause of the errors you have seen.

Hi, Thanks for the tip, but I'm still receiving data type mismatch errors.  The string I'm passing in has this format:  Thu May  2 12:42:42 2024.  I receive now a new error, 'Data type mismatch in criteria expression.'  To check the modified, I just used Date() as the criteria.  Currently, the function returns 1/2/1900 as the result, but I can get that fixed.  Any thoughts on why still the data type mismatch?

You should include example of data within your question.

That input takes a little more parsing. See edited answer, please.

Add an If Then test in your code to see if input is valid date before trying to parse
Public Function cvt2date(deviceLocalTime As String) As Date
Dim m, d, y, new_date As String
new_Date = deviceLocalTime
If Not IsDate(new_Date) Then
    If new_Date = "" Then
       new_date = "1/2/1900"
    Else
       y = Right(new_Date, 4)
       m = Mid(new_Date, 5, 3)
       d = Mid(new_Date, 9, 2)
       new_date = m & "/" & d & "/" & y
    End If
End If
cvt2date = CDate(new_date)
End Function

Make sure never to pass Null to function because that will error since you declare the input argument as a string. If field could possibly be Null, use Nz() function to pass alternate value which could be "1/2/1900".

Thanks.  The updated function did return values as dates, 5/2/2024 as example.  Unfortunately, when I added Date() as my search criteria, I got the same type mismatch runtime error 13 at cvt2date = CDate(new_date) in the function.  Should I be using different criteria to select the desired date range in the query?

I tested with Date() and Now() as inputs and function works. Have you tested by calling function from Immediate Window? Edit question to show SQL and sample data as a formatted text table or start a new question.
